# Mono.Data.Sqlite throws exceptions

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono

I'm using SQLite as database engine in my app, but at the same time the application must be cross-platform, so i have decided to use Mono.Data.Sqlite. And this what i did:

- Installed the latest version of Mono (4.0.2 SR 2), copied Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll from Mono's directory (net4_5) to my project in Visual Studio 2015
- Downloaded and copied precompiled sqlite3.dll library.

And then i wrote a simple app:

```
        const string databaseFileName = "somedata.db";
        var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + databaseFileName;

        if (!File.Exists(path)) SqliteConnection.CreateFile(databaseFileName);

        var connString = string.Format("Data Source=file:{0}", databaseFileName);

        using (var conn = new SqliteConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            /* Some code */
            conn.ChangePassword("testpassword");
            conn.Close();
        }
```

But i'm facing with some issues:

- First, when i'm using **Data Source=file:{0}** in connection string, it throws an exception: "URI formats are not supported". Replacing it to **URI=file:{0}** helps, but why the first option doesn't work?
- Second, when i call **conn.ChangePassword("testpassword")** it throws an exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry  point named "sqlite3_rekey" in DLL "sqlite3"
- Third, using **URI=file:{0};Password=testpassword**  with the already encrypted database throws an exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry  point named "sqlite3_key" in DLL "sqlite3"

It doesn't actually happen with official wrapper for SQLite, but happens with Mono's.

P.S. Mono's wrapper works normally when i don't use encryption and **Data Source=file:{0}** instead of **URI=file:{0}**

P.S.S. Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 + latest version of Mono and SQLite

Comment: The second and third items are because it can not find the native dll that the Mono version is trying to p/invoke. Just copying the CIL based dll is not enough.

Comment: I have already mentioned that i copied native sqlite library and besides, have you read postscript?

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, convert your URI to a local file path; `new Uri(databaseFileURI).LocalPath`. The `file://` or `file:` is not used by Sqlite and stripped by the C# helper code, see the code in "Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteConnection.cs".

For the second/third issues:

The sqlite3 native lib that you have appears to not match the Mono's dll import statements, you can use `bindump /EXPORTS` to confirm this. The Mono DllImports and the matching SQLite .h exports follows:

NOTE: This of course assumes you are have the correct ARCH for the native dll and you are not compiling a Uni-app in Windows.

Grep'ing out the source of "Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs"

> Second, when i call conn.ChangePassword("testpassword") it throws an
>   exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry
>   point named "sqlite3_rekey" in DLL "sqlite3"

```
#if !PLATFORM_COMPACTFRAMEWORK
    [DllImport(SQLITE_DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#else
    [DllImport(SQLITE_DLL)]
#endif
    internal static extern int sqlite3_key(IntPtr db, byte[] key, int keylen);
```

> Third, using URI=file:{0};Password=testpassword with the already
>   encrypted database throws an exception:
>   System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point
>   named "sqlite3_key" in DLL "sqlite3"

```
#if !PLATFORM_COMPACTFRAMEWORK
    [DllImport(SQLITE_DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#else
    [DllImport(SQLITE_DLL)]
#endif
    internal static extern int sqlite3_rekey(IntPtr db, byte[] key, int keylen);
```

The matching sqlite.h defines:

```
...
SQLITE_API int SQLITE_STDCALL sqlite3_rekey
...
SQLITE_API int SQLITE_STDCALL sqlite3_key
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but using **Data Source={0}** in connection string now works. BTW, about 2/3 issues - so i need to find right dll that contains these entry points?

Comment: If the native sqlite dll that you have does not have those entry points, then yes. I'm not sure where you got yours from, but there is note on sqlite.org's site about compiling it for Mono...  Unless there is a hard reason to use Mono's assemblies, you can just grab one of the Sqlite PCL nugets (or related source), like SQLite-net PCL from praeclarum

Comment: I downloaded it from official website: **32-bit DLL (x86) for SQLite verison 3.8.11.1** (section *Precompiled Binaries for Windows*)

Comment: I'm also facing with these issues with latest Mono on Ubuntu http://i58.tinypic.com/24xmkc6.jpg

Comment: Interesting, I have mono 4.0.3 on an Ubuntu TLS 14 server and have no problems with sqlite. Also just grabbed the latest sqllite (3.8.11.1 source and compiled it for three xplats and no problems (os-x 10.10.x, win8.1/10 or linux...)

Comment: @maque Did you use a pkg version of mono or build from source? Also which version of mono is it (version number and git sha)

Comment: Light bulb goes on, you both do not have the sqlite SQLCipher version, thus key and rekey are not available, I'm compiling from source and have sqlcipher. I would 'assume' the stock SQLite downloads available on their site would not include sqlcipher. Just download the sources and compile it

Comment: I have installed mono via **sudo apt-get install mono-complete**

Comment: Mono would not supply a sqlcipher based libsqlite3.so, they do support its use, but there is nothing in their C source that includes it in the build. Either get it from a pkg install or compile it yourself. I know that node.js and other packages support it also but require that you compile it yourself. I have a master build VM for each OS and package sqlite (and lots of other things ) for publishing via chef, etc... Check the sqlcipher package on Ubuntu, not sure it that is just the cmd line interface or not...