# Build c# for mac

Tags: c#, macos, sqlite, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm trying to build the System.Data.SQLite library for MAC.

I have built the libSQLite.Interop.so following this example : https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=Setup%2Fcompile-interop-assembly-release.sh

My Unity project contains my libSQLite.Interop.so (built from my linux computer) and my System.Data.SQLite.dll (built from windows).

When I build my application for MAC using Unity it launches but it can't load the library.

Here is the logs :

> Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.dylib
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.so
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.bundle
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/SQLite.Interop.dll
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dylib
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.so Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.bundle
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/SQLite.Interop
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.dylib
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.so
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.bundle
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.dylib
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.so
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.bundle
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/SQLite.Interop.dll
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dylib
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.so Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.bundle
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/SQLite.Interop
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.dylib
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.so
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll.bundle
>   Fallback handler could not load library
>   /Users/victor/Desktop/BUILD_MAC.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libSQLite.Interop.dll
>   DllNotFoundException: SQLite.Interop.dll   at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConfigOpsEnum)
>   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized () [0x0001c] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor (System.String
>   connectionString, System.Boolean parseViaFramework) [0x00021] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor (System.String
>   connectionString) [0x00000] in :0
>   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(string)   at
>   LibLOCA.Localisation.LoadLanguage (LibLOCA.GameLanguage language)
>   [0x0004a] in :0

Did I miss anything in the process ? I guess I did something wrong while mixing the builts but it's really confusing me.

**EDIT**
I've managed to build it using the script and I've put the new dylib file in the Managed folder of the build. It seems to work but when I open my database I have the following exception :

System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named "sqlite3_rekey" in DLL "sqlite3"

Seems like this person had a similar issue : [Mono.Data.Sqlite throws exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733738/mono-data-sqlite-throws-exceptions)
But I don't understand the solution, I can see the lines in the code but I don't understand what I should change to make it work.

**EDIT2** I've added -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 to the script and now the build doesn't work anymore I have the following exceptions :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_sqlite3CodecAttach", referenced from: _attachFun in interop-523232.o
>   "_sqlite3CodecGetKey", referenced from: _sqlite3RunVqcuum in interop-523232.o
>   _attachFunc in interop-523232.o

Comment: `...libSQLite.Interop.so (built from my linux computer)...` Are you **cross-compiling** that shared library for macOS? The correct ARCH 32/64bit? The shell script you linked to is NOT cross-compiling...it make is simple, just use the same script to compile the `.dylib` on macOS itself.

Comment: I thought building on linux would work on macOS, my macOS is a virtual machine so it's not the most stable environment to work with. I'll try to build it on mac then thank you. Do I need to include both .so and .dylib in my project ?

Comment: `Do I need to include both...` If you are packaging one bundle that installs/run on both Linux and macOS (and Windows?), then yes, you would need to distribute the native binaries for each platform with that bundle).

Comment: I've managed to include the dylib I think but I have an exception, would you have a solution for it ? I've seen you answered this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733738/mono-data-sqlite-throws-exceptions 
But I don't really understand the solution, I found the lines but what should I change to make it work